# why mapping not returns "value"?

Tags: solidity

I am calling the function `getPrice()` with arguments `tokenId` but it returns 0, while i have assigned `price = 1 ether`, where is the problem in this code?

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

import "./S5Implement.sol";

  contract newToken is S5Implement {

      uint256 private price = 1 ether;

      mapping (uint256 => uint256) private priceMapping;

      function getPrice(uint256 _tokenId) public returns(uint256) {

           price = priceMapping[_tokenId];

      }
  }
```

Comment: You are not actually `return`ing any value

Comment: i have checked it with return too but same it returns 0, while i the `price  = 1 ether `

Comment: Well you are overwriting the value of `price` - it's probably 0.

Comment: `pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

import "./S5Implement.sol";

  contract newToken is S5Implement {
      
      uint256 private price = 1 ether;
      
      mapping (uint256 => uint256) private priceMapping;
      
      function getPrice(uint256 _tokenId) public returns(uint256) {
           
           price = priceMapping[_tokenId];
          return price;
      }
  }`

this is the code

Comment: please correct it if it is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You need to return value from mapping instead of overriding. Read [documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.8) here.

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.7;

import "./S5Implement.sol";

contract newToken is S5Implement {

      uint256 private price = 1 ether;

      mapping (uint256 => uint256) private priceMapping;

      function getPrice(uint256 _tokenId) public view returns(uint256) {
           return priceMapping[_tokenId];
      }
  }
```